# ExtJs 4.2 editable grid handling response

Tags: javascript, php, extjs, extjs4.2

I have a model,a store and a grid:

**MODEL**

```
Ext.define('demo.mdlTemaco', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
         {name: 'id',                               type: 'string'      , mapping: ''},
         {name: 'id_empresa',                       type: 'string'      , mapping: ''},
         {name: 'cif',                              type: 'string'      , mapping: ''},
         {name: 'acronimo',                         type: 'string'      , mapping: ''},
         {name: 'competidor',                       type: 'string'      , mapping: ''},
         {name: 'descripcion',                      type: 'text'        , mapping: ''}
]
});
```

**STORE**

```
Ext.define('demo.strTemaco', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
model:  'demo.mdlTemaco',
autoLoad: false,
autoSync: true,
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    pageParam: undefined,
    startParam: undefined,
    limitParam: undefined,

    api: {
        read: 'read.php',
        update: 'update.php',
        create: ''
    },
    reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'data',
                idProperty: 'id',
                totalProperty: 'total',
                successProperty: 'success',
                messageProperty : 'message',
    },
    writer: {
        root: 'records',
        encode: true,
        writeAllFields: true
    }
}
});
```

**GRID**

```
var cellEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing',{
        clicksToEdit: 2
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
itemId:'viewGridTemaco',
        title:'<span style="color:#C85E00;">Title</span>',
        store: Ext.create('demo.strTemaco'),
        stripeRows: true,
        loadMask: true,
        selType: 'checkboxmodel',
        plugins: [cellEditing],
        columns:{
            defaults:{
                hideable:false,
                draggable:false
            },
            items:[
                   {header:'<span style="color:#C85E00;">Id</span>'         ,dataIndex:'id'             ,itemId:'IdConcurso'    ,flex:1     },
                   {header:'<span style="color:#C85E00;">Empresa</span>'    ,dataIndex:'id_empresa'     ,itemId:'Empresa'       ,flex:1     },
                   {header:'<span style="color:#C85E00;">CIF</span>'        ,dataIndex:'cif'            ,itemId:'CIF'           ,flex:2     ,editor:{allorBlanck:false}},
                   {header:'<span style="color:#C85E00;">Acronimo</span>'   ,dataIndex:'acronimo'       ,itemId:'Acronimo'      ,flex:2     ,editor:{allorBlanck:false}},
                   {header:'<span style="color:#C85E00;">Competidor</span>' ,dataIndex:'competidor'     ,itemId:'Competidor'    ,flex:3     ,editor:{allorBlanck:false}},
                   {header:'<span style="color:#C85E00;">Descripcion</span>',dataIndex:'descripcion'    ,itemId:'Descripcion'   ,flex:3     ,editor:{allorBlanck:false}}
            ]   
        }
renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

In my controller I have a listener to handle the editing of the cell:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('viewGridTemaco')[0].getStore().addListener('update',function(store, record, operation, modifiedFieldNames, eOpts){
            store.commitChanges();
        },this);
```

And in the update php if there is an error for some reasons I send:

```
echo json_encode(array(
"success"   => //A number between 1-5 depending on the error
));
```

And I want to handle this response in the controller to show a message box.Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: As per the ExtJS docs, the `success` property has to be a boolean.

Comment: I have changed "success"=>1 to "success"=>true,but in the controller where and how I control this success true/false?

Comment: In the store sync callback, which cannot be used with `autoSync:true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved the probled disabling autoSync in store and in the contoller,in update listener I use:

```
store.sync({
                scope:this,
                success : function(response){

                },
                failure:function(response){
                    var mensaje;
                    switch(Ext.JSON.decode(response.operations[0].error)) 
                    {
                        case 1:
                            mensaje="Messagge 1";
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            mensaje="Messagge 2";
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            mensaje="Messagge 3";
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            mensaje="Messagge 4";
                            break;
                    }
                    Ext.Msg.show({ 
                        title: 'ADVERTENCIA', 
                        msg:mensaje,
                        icon: Ext.MessageBox.WARNING, 
                        buttons: Ext.Msg.OK,
                        closable:false
                    });
                    store.rejectChanges();
                }
            });
```

And my update.php response is:

```
echo json_encode(array(
"success"   => false,
"message"   => //number between 1-5
));
```

Comment: You found by yourself ! :) But just for the line : ```response.operations[0].error``` try to use ```response.operations[0].getError()```. Even better, iterate trough operations, because you never know if sync() will not do more operations...